# Flutter: Show Interstitial Ads after Splash Screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, admob, splash-screen, interstitial

in my **Flutter** APP, when a user launches the app, a splash screen is shown after that he is forwarded to the homeScreen.

my goal is to show an admob interstitial ad between the splash screen and the homescreen.
something like this : [see this post from google](https://www.blog.google/products/admob/using-splash-pages-to-avoid-unexpected-launch-interstitials/)
[image]

i have tried many options, but unfortunately without luck.

does anyone have a code / idea how to implement this in flutter.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps:

> There are 2 scenarios where user will be navigated to the home screen:
>
> 1. Either user closes the ad after the ad is shown.
> 2. Or ad fails to load.

```
class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  SplashScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    _createInterstitialAd();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _interstitialAd?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  InterstitialAd? _interstitialAd;
  int _numInterstitialLoadAttempts = 0;
  int maxFailedLoadAttempts = 3;

  void _createInterstitialAd() {
    InterstitialAd.load(
      adUnitId: "YOUR-AD-UNIT-ID",
      request: AdRequest(),
      adLoadCallback: InterstitialAdLoadCallback(
        onAdLoaded: (InterstitialAd ad) {
          _interstitialAd = ad;
          _numInterstitialLoadAttempts = 0;
          _showInterstitialAd();
        },
        onAdFailedToLoad: (LoadAdError error) {
          _numInterstitialLoadAttempts += 1;
          _interstitialAd = null;
          if (_numInterstitialLoadAttempts < maxFailedLoadAttempts) {
            _createInterstitialAd();
          } else {
            Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen()),
              (route) => false,
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  void _showInterstitialAd() {
    if (_interstitialAd == null) {
      print('Warning: attempt to show interstitial before loaded.');
      return;
    }
    _interstitialAd!.fullScreenContentCallback = FullScreenContentCallback(
      onAdDismissedFullScreenContent: (InterstitialAd ad) {
        ad.dispose();
        Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen()),
          (route) => false,
        );
      },
    );
    _interstitialAd!.show();
    _interstitialAd = null;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Text("Your Splash Screen"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```